# Jquery: change opacity on menu hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an fixed menu that i want to change opacity when scrolled down and back up, so I made this:

JQuery: https://paste.ee/p/Ew9UW

HTML: https://paste.ee/p/5PTOE

CSS: https://paste.ee/p/RCtLj

Its working how i want, but i want to add one thing and I have no idea how.
I want to change opacity back to 1.0 when I hover over the menu bar at any point of the site (top middle bottom, it must work everywhere)
Any idea how to make it?

**[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/145/)**

**JS :**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 70) {
        $("nav").css("opacity", "0.2");
    }
    else {
        $("nav").css("opacity", "1");
    }   
});
```

Thansk for your help

Comment: include the relevant code in the OP not just a link

Comment: let me give you idea to do this. if you are not able to do it by yourself then post your code again.
So do like this: dont apply opacity directly on scrolling. create one class in css which have that new opacity and apply it when you are at your required scroll position.
now if you want to use hover event then apply your new opacity on hover method. so this will override your current class property.

Comment: code is in the link, im not able to use CTRL+k on it for some reason it just doesnt work for me. sorry

Comment: **You don't need to create fiddle links. Just use the tools SO has...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecvcc5k3/)**

first of all, `nav` is a class of an `ul` , so to call it you need to put a `.` in front of it `.nav`

second, just add `!important` to `.nav:hover{opacity:1!important}` so that it will overwrite the JQ. it's the **quickest** way...not the **best** way

code :

```
.nav:hover {
    opacity: 1!important;
    transition: 0.01s;
    background-color: #111;
    transition: 0.3s;

}
```

**OR** . a nicer way to do it is like this **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecvcc5k3/1/)**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 70) {
        $(".nav").addClass("opac");
    }
    else {
        $(".nav").removeClass("opac")
    }   
});
```

CSS :

```
.nav.opac {opacity:0.2}
.nav.opac:hover { opacity:1;}
```

Add a class `.opac` to the `.nav` when scroll and then style that class in CSS. so no need for that ugly `!important`

Comment: Exactly what i wanted.  Even the quickest way is sometimes the best. I know there is a way to make it "better" but this is enough. I didnt know that !important element exist but now i know. Thank you very much

Comment: edited with a nicer way to do it. you choose. glad i could help. don't forget to rate my answer as the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change the opacity value in the **.nav:hover** rule in your CSS:

```
.nav:hover{
    opacity: 1.0 !important;
}
```

I would choose the CSS way in terms of performance. Don't overuse JS animation and go with CSS instead.